# WPF + Binding Command and Header of a Context Menu Item using MVVM

Tags: wpf, mvvm, binding, header, command

I created a WPF application and am following MVVM Pattern.  I have a context menu in my xaml and I need to bind the command and Header text.  Using the following code I can bind the Header of the context menu with the "MenuItemName" which is a property in BOList which is an observable collection.  My issue is that command is not getting fired?  I changes the Item source of the Context Menu to datacontext

```
(DataContext="{Binding Path=PlacementTarget.Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}")
```

Command is working fine but my header is getting blank. Is there a way to bind my header and command of a menu item?  Here the command MenuClick is a Icommand property in the VM and MenuItemName is a property inside BOList which is an observable collection binded to my ListBox.

```
<Grid>
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
   <Button x:Name="btnClickMe" Command="{Binding ButtonCommand}" Content="Click Me" />
  <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding BOList}" x:Name="lstDemo" SelectedItem="{Binding BussinessObj,Mode=OneWayToSource}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
        <StackPanel x:Name="stkStyleRender" Orientation="Horizontal" Background="Cyan" Width="525"  Tag="{Binding DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListBox}}}" >
          <TextBlock x:Name="txtId" Text="{Binding FirstName}"></TextBlock>
          <TextBlock x:Name="txtName" Text="{Binding LastName}"></TextBlock>
          <StackPanel.ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu x:Name="cntMnuTest" ItemsSource ="{Binding Path=PlacementTarget.Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" >
              <MenuItem Header="{Binding MenuItemName}"  Command="{Binding MenuClick}" CommandParameter="Icon"></MenuItem>
            </ContextMenu> 
          </StackPanel.ContextMenu>

        </StackPanel>
      </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
 </ListBox>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: what does the MenuItemName look like in the ViewModel? look in the console output for a Beinding Expression error too, and post what it is if you see it.

Answer (score 1):

Hi Identified the issue.

If we set Item Source of the context menu to BOList (observable collection ) command wont get fired because the `ICommand` definition is in Window data context (vm).

We need to handle the code like wise.

Since debugging is not possible for binding , I was beating around the bush :-)

This link helped me a lot [WPF Tutorial - Debug Databinding Issues in WPF](http://wpftutorial.net/DebugDataBinding.html)

Answer (score 0):

In context menu use DataContext instead of using Items source 
 
then bind your menu item

Comment: I tried it , if datacontext is set Command works but header property binding fails ,, if item source is set Header binding works but command binding  fails ,,,

Comment: Hi Identified the issue . If we set Item Source of the context menu  to BOList (observable collection ) command wont get fired because the icommand definition is in Window data ciontext (vm). We need to handle the code like wise . Since debugging is not possible for binding , I was beating around the bush :-) .. THIS Link helped me a lot http://www.wpftutorial.net/DebugDataBinding.html

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<MenuItem Header="{Binding Path=PlacementTarget.MenuItemName, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ContextMenu}}"  Command="{Binding Path=PlacementTarget.MenuClick, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ContextMenu}}" />
```

Comment: If u set DataContext then command bindinng happens and if we set item source header binding happens .. ???                             <ContextMenu x:Name="cntMnuTest" ItemsSource ="{Binding Path=PlacementTarget.Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" >
              <MenuItem Header="{Binding MenuItemName}"  Command="{Binding MenuClick}" CommandParameter="Icon"></MenuItem>
            </ContextMenu>